# React Function calling Function Method for HTML

Tags: reactjs

Is having a Functional Method being called in the Main Function bad practice? Below , my ProductDashboard is calling productbody html and other components (in different files) . Is having"return productBody" an incorrect practice? I want to isolate some of the extra html into a method within the component, instead of a separate file.

*If not, is there an alternative to isolate the html without using another file?

My code currently works regardless.

citing this article: https://dev.to/igor_bykov/react-calling-functional-components-as-functions-1d3l

```
const ProductDashboard = () => {

   const productBody = () => {
    return (
      <Box>
         <ProductHeader/>
         <ProductList
           productId={encounter.patientId}
           serviceLocationId={encounter.serviceLocationGuid}
           showTotalBalance
          />
      ......
      </Box>
     
    );
   };

  return (
    <Box data-testid="financial-information">
      {(() => {
        if (loadingError) {
          return <LoadingError />;
        } else if (isLoading) {
          return <CircularLoading />;
        } else if (encounter == null || encounter?.length === 0) {
          return <EncounterAlert />;
        } else {
          return productBody;   // <<---- this line here
        }
      })()}
```

Comment: Should you not call the function?

Comment: hi @Rajesh I want to render the html in the function, Im not sure if I fully understand the comment

Comment: If I understand correct, you need the markup (JSX not HTML) in `productBody`. If yes, it should be `return productBody()` instead

Comment: return productBody is working, do you want me to use productBody() paranthesis then? cc @Rajesh

Comment: hi @Rajesh I am citing this article by the way https://dev.to/igor_bykov/react-calling-functional-components-as-functions-1d3l